# Send two forms one button in django, fix error

Tags: javascript, html, django

in django template I have code

```
 {% include 'temp/first_page.html' %}
 {% include 'temp/last_page.html' %}
```

in these two templates two different form, example at first:

`<form name='first'> </form>`

in second:

`<form name='second'> </form>`

when I send these form by one button with code:

```
document.forms['first'].submit();
document.forms['second'].submit();`
```

sometimes I get just second form, first not sending in POST. How can I fix this error?

Comment: `submit()` in javascript submits the form using **one** HTTP request. Your browser is then waiting for a response from your server. But it doesn't halt javascript execution. So since you're immediately sending a second `submit()` after that, you're actually sending **two** separate HTTP requests to your server. You should see both on your server. The big problem is that your browser will only react to **one** response, whichever comes first. So this will never work correctly.

Comment: If you want to submit both forms as one form, don't wrap each one in a separate <form> tag, but wrap your entire page (the two includes) in **one** <form> tag that you submit with a regular submit button. That way all fields from both forms will be submitted with one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`submit()` in javascript submits the form using **one** HTTP request. Your browser is then waiting for a response from your server. But it doesn't halt javascript execution.

So since you're immediately sending a second `submit()` after that, you're actually sending **two** separate HTTP requests to your server (*). You should see both on your server and you should see your view being called twice. The big problem is that your browser will only react to **one** response, whichever comes first probably (not sure, the second one might interrupt the first one actually). So this will never work correctly.

You should have only one `<form>` tag in your page and submit that as one form:

```
<form method="post">
    {% include 'temp/first_page.html' %}
    {% include 'temp/last_page.html' %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

(*) It's unlikely that the response for the first submit reaches the browser before it gets to the second submit.

Note: To ensure the various fields have unique names, you might want to [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) each form, if both forms have similar fields.